# Dynamically created image's onclick() not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load all images in a folder into a div (id="wrap") But it's click function not working. why?

Below is my code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var folder = 'images/print/thumb/'
        post_data = {'folder':folder};

        $.post('get_images.php', post_data, function(images){
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

                var tag = '<img class="thumb"  src="' + folder + images[i] + '" />';

                $("#wrap").prepend(tag);
            }

        }, 'json');

        $(".thumb").click(function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });

    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="wrap" style="padding:20px;">
    </div>
</body>
```

It loads the images perfectly. Only problem is with the click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to place the event registering part inside of the ajax call back,

```
 $.post('get_images.php', post_data, function(images) {

       for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
         var tag = '<img class="thumb"  src="' + folder + images[i] + '" />';
         $("#wrap").prepend(tag);
       }

        $(".thumb").click(function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });   

 }, 'json');
```

Or the best way would be using the `event delegation`,

```
 $("#wrap").on("click", ".thumb", function(){
    alert(this.id);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Id id the job. But, binding it with '.on' works perfect. The .click fails sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer is accepted, I think it needs a little explanation for beginners.

jQuery doesn't bind events to dynamic elements directly. We need to get the help of a static ancestor element for tracking those events. That's what it does here:

```
$("#wrap").on("click", ".thumb", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

in human language, when a `click` event happens on any child having class `thumb` of `#wrap`, do this. I've seen many people use `document` as the parent element. But the best practice is to use the immediately available static parent, otherwise the documents needs to be scanned all the way down the DOM tree to find the happened element.

Or even you can add an `onclick` event to the dynamic element at the time of inserting it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
         var tag = '<img class="thumb" onclick="myFunction()"  src="' + folder + images[i] + '" />';
         $("#wrap").prepend(tag);
       }
```

then

```
function myFunction() {
    // stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps beginners.